# javax.swing.text.BadLocationException when trying to remove text from doc

Tags: java, swing, text, document

I am trying to remove/delete some text from a document between two points.
Say if I have a document with the text "1234XS", I am trying to remove the text "XS", which is between index 4 and 5. However, I am getting `BadLocationException` error when I try removing it. Here is what I have:

```
System.out.println(tp.getText().length());//tp is a JTextPane. prints out 6, just to show I'm not going out of bounds
System.out.println(position+ "-" + (position+ 1));//prints out 4 and 5
tp.getStyledDocument().remove(position, (position + 1));//crashes here, trying to remove "XS" from "1234XS"
```

Comment: Where are you trying to remove this? In a DocumentListener? If so, don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
remove(position, position + 1)
```

The parameters for the `remove(...)` method is not the `start` and `end` offset.

The parameters are the `start` and `length`. So the code should be:

```
remove(position, 1)
```